# SQL database on GitHub using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, github, localhost

Is it possible to export a `*.sql` file and use it on my GitHub account? If yes, how can I do it? My code works on local host, I have no experience in putting websites on external server.

Here is the code in PHP:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "*here is my username*";
$password = "*here is my password*";
$dbName = "*here is my database name*";
//utworzenie połączenia
try {
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName;dbname=$dbName", $userName, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "No connection: " . $e->getMessage();
}                     
$connection->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: FYI, you should put your credentials in a separate file that doesn't get checked into your GitHub and then include it in your main file for security reasons

Comment: This is pretty unclear. How can an SQL file (or any other file) be used on a Github account? Don't be afraid to be verbose and give examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github doesn’t provide any web hosting that can be used to do what you want. Github allows you to remotely store projects in the form of git repositories. If you want to create a website, you’ll need to look for a webserver to publish it. Github Pages only support static content, so no PHP nor database there.

A few other things:

- `.sql` files holds SQL commands, like `SELECT` or `CREATE`. If you want a database, you’ll need a MySQL (or other) instance.
- As already said by @Jonathan Rys, never check any credentials to a repository on github. Keep them separate. You don’t want anybody to be able to read your passwords.

Have fun in you web development journey!